# Using hard disk for fast access replacing RAM

Tags: c++, c, linux, memory

I have been running a memory intensive C++ linux application on a machine with high memory(128GB RAM). This application reserves about 20GB of memory beforehand to use it later as buffers. I wish to port this application to some kind of SBC like a Raspberry Pi where I practically have no memory to use (when compared to the usual scenario). My thought process here is to use the HDD (possibly a SDD) instead of RAM for allocating the 20GB of memory. Is there a more efficient way to do this? Also, in this approach, what should my implementation be: just binary files or something else?

Edit: I can reduce the memory allocation to less like say 2GB. Still, I do not have that kinda memory available in the RPi. Since the whole project is to port it to an SBC, I need to resolve it just with harddisk space.

Comment: **In general:** secondary memory is never as fast as the primary memory.

Comment: Wouldn't creating a swap file be an easier solution? In this way, you would not have to change our application at all.

Comment: @MatthiasDiener : Using a swap file and allocating a 20GB buffer would cause the system and every other process to swap as well. This would likely almost freeze the system, this is a bad idea. The OP idea is better

Comment: You can (should) decrease the amount of memory the program sets aside for buffers to what is viable in the Pi. Or, as others suggest, you could replace the whole mechanism with something that is more appropriate for the small machine.

Comment: If you have the possibility to plug a hdd, you could use a hardware ram disk.

Comment: does your SBC support "Memory Mapped Files"?

Answer (score 3):

I would first consider to use `mmap` to map the file as if swap.

Then, rpi uses 32-bit ARM, this means you can't have all 20GB address at the same time, so you need some kind of memory overlay method:

1. your program explicitly request your "memory controller" to swap in/out on regions.
2. you adopt patterns like lock-buffer (similar to what Direct3D does), and have the "memory controller" manage and do the swapping.

Bottom line, rpi is not suitable for the job, you would need to invest high development cost than simply picking a cheap PC.

Comment: Last sentence appears entirely subjective. Are you aware of more details of user2779853's job than the rest of us are? How many instances of this will be deployed(N), what is the unit cost of a Pi, what is the unit-cost of N lots of 24Gb or more of memory, what is the cost of the time taken to approach the particular task differently? In my opinion, the last sentence dilutes what is an otherwise good answer.

Comment: I agree it is my own opinion, based on consideration of development cost involved to fix a non-problem. We may also provide more alternative to solve the problem if OP provide more detail on his application. By the way, getting an 64-bit embedded may make the development much simpler.

Comment: @enhzflep - agreed, still +1 to Calvin

Answer (score 1):

I would not dare port an application written for a 128Go memory machine that actually reserves 20 Go of memory for its buffers on a low resource machine without further analyses. As secondary memory is seldom as fast as main memory, you could have to refactor the memory management of the application, with *explicit swapping* as we did in the 70s or the early 80s:

- define n zones of real memory that will be available for the job
- store to full data on a random access file on disk
- explicitely load (and store modified data) when needed

This pattern has been no longer used for ages, because common computer now have plenty of memory and are fast enough to let the OS provide virtual memory with swap and not bother the progammer with such a tedious task.

But as soon as you want to run a *memory intensive C++ application* on a Raspberry Pi, you fall in the old problems where optimization of resource usage was critic.